# What a values would make this System of Linear equations True?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to solve this system of equations to know which values of $a$ makes it true.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&2&a\\
      1&2&a&2\\
      2&3&4+a&3a+1 
    \end{array}
\right] $$
Where this augmented matrix represents the system of equations with $z, y, z$ variables.

So far I have done this:
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&2&a\\
      0&1&a-2&2-a\\
      0&0&-2&2a-1 
    \end{array}
\right] $$

by elementary operations on the matrix. (So that $-2z = 2a - 1$).

But then, I try to manipulate in such a way that expresses the x, y and z in terms of a, but I can't seem to get anywhere further.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from equation (I) we get
$$z=\frac{a-x-y}{2}$$ plugging this in (II),(III) we obtain
$$x(2-a)+y(4-a)=4-a^2$$
and $$-ax+y(2-a)=2+2a-a^2$$
now we are doing case work:
$$a=0$$: then we get $$y=1,x=0$$
$$a\ne 0$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{a^2-2a-2+y(2-a)}{a}$$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reduced form of the augmented matrix does not have any rows of the form $$\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      0&0&0&c
    \end{array}
\right]$$ for nonzero $c$. So the system is consistent for all values of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to PJK's answer.

The determinant of the coefficient matrix is non-zero (independent of $a$):
$$\begin{vmatrix}   
1&1&2\\
1&2&a\\
2&3&4+a
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}   
1&1&2\\
0&1&a-2\\
0&1&a
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}   
1&a-2\\
1&a
\end{vmatrix}=2 \ne 0$$
So the system has a unique solution for all $a$.